# Timedata convertion unsuccessfull

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to create a Python Bot that takes a qr code from my email and sends it to me via Telegram when i want to.
I was able to convert the email data in a list, in this way i am also able to access the date  written in the email.

for context the email looks like this:

> Gentile STEFANO ZIZZI,
>
> La tua prenotazione per l'evento ANALISI MATEMATICA 1 in data
> 01/03/2022 09:00 è stata confermata.
>
> L'aula in cui potrai seguire l'evento è: Aula Von Neumann.
>
> Stampa e porta con te il seguente codice a barre:
>
> 20220222090620-ffc5d11f-760c-4449-975f-*********

So i have this multidimentional list where the elements are:
0 - the qr code
1 - the place
2 - the subject
3 - the date

and looks like this:

> [['20220222090620-ffc5d11f-760c-4449-975f-********'], ['Aula Von
> Neumann.'], ['ANALISI MATEMATICA 1 '], ['01/03/2022 09:00']]

Why by running this code, it does not convert the date to datetime succeffuly?

```
data =''.join(lista[0][3])
if data:
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(data,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
    print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

Sorry if there's not the full code but it's honestly too long to copy here, and i think i've given most of the information anyways.

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '01/03/2022 09:00' does not match format
'%d/%m/%y %H:%M'
```

Comment: Use `Y` instead of `y`

Answer (score 1):

To match the date 2022 you must use the %Y, as %y refers to year displayed with 2 digits.

```
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(data,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```